# Export all stickies at once on OS X 10.8?

Tags: macos, backup, file-conversion

I am using Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8). I have a lot of stickies, but have been unable to find a simple way to export *all* the stickies at once as either text or HTML.

Have I overlooked something obvious? What is the right way to export all stickies *in bulk* into a more open file format?

Comment: All stickies are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/widget-com.apple.widget.stickies.plist` and could be extracted from there.

Comment: @patrix They are in a database format; there is no *obvious* way to extract the stickies to text and/or HTML from the native format of the stickies database.

Comment: Err, I just realized that there are different apps for Stickies. One is a Dashboard widget, the other one a "real" application. Which one are you talking about?

Answer (score 3):

### Export stickies created by Stickies.app

1. Install [Notational Velocity (NV)](http://notational.net/) and start the application
2. In Finder open your `Library` folder and locate `StickiesDatabase`
3. Drag `StickiesDatabase` into the 'Filtered Note List' in the NV main window (see [here](https://github.com/scrod/nv/wiki/importing-notes-from-external-sources) for reference)
4. In NV select any number of notes and choose `Export` from the menu

If you prefer to write your own code, have a look at [Learning Cocoa with Objective-C](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2005/03/18/cocoa.html) which explains how to reverse-engineer the `StickiesDatabase` format.

### Export Dashboard stickies

Run this in Terminal.app

```
plutil -convert json -r -o - ~/Library/Preferences/widget-com.apple.widget.stickies.plist |
    awk '$1 ~ /-data/ { start=index($0, ":")+3
                        end=length($0)-2
                        sticky=substr($0, start, end-start+1)
                        gsub(/<.?.?div>/, "", sticky)
                        gsub(/<br>/, "\n", sticky)
                        print sticky
                        print "---" }' > ~/all-my-stickies.txt
```

Comment: This program worked great in Mountain Lion. Now I have to figure out how to import the files into Notes. Thanks, Jim

Answer (score 2):

Below is a modified version of [this script](http://hints.macworld.com/dlfiles/stickies_export_scpt.txt).  It exports your stickies into separate txt files.

```
osascript <<'APPLESCRIPT'

set theName to ""
set i to 0
set n to {}
set L to {}

# prompt for output dir
set destFldr to (choose folder with prompt "Choose a destination folder:") as text
# hardcode output dir
#set destFldr to "/path/to/export/to/" as text
set mydestFldr to POSIX path of destFldr

tell application "Stickies"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "Stickies"
            set L to name of every window
            try
                repeat with awindow in L
                    set m to value of text area 1 of scroll area 1 of window awindow
                    set i to i + 1
                    set theName to "stickies" & "_" & i & ".txt" as string
                    set theFile to mydestFldr & theName
                    do shell script "/bin/echo " & quoted form of m & " > " & quoted form of theFile
                end repeat
            end try
        end tell
    end tell
    # display dialog "done"
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        open destFldr
    end tell
end tell
APPLESCRIPT
```

Note that this will only grab all the stickies from the current Mac 'Space'.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are simpler ways to do it as well.

1. Turn on your Apple Computer & Go to the Library folder
2. Select the file named “StickiesDatabase”
3. Copy the file and save it somewhere else to backup stickies

Refer http://www.macworld.com/article/1160992/software-utilities/transfer-stickies.html for more details.